# Deconvolution vs convolution.

Tags: convolution

This is now a second time I am attempting to ask this very important but simple question here. What I want to know is can you do deconvolution by convolving a signal. It is often stated that, for example by cutting and boosting the same frequency on an equalizer the result is the original signal. Is that the case? Can convolution be removed by convolving? That would certainly brake the identity that the convolved signal must be n+m-1 in length.

If the above can be done, I can not arrive at this conclusion. For example If I convolve (1) with (1, 1) the result is (1, 1). I can not find any impulse response that if convolved with (1, 1) would result in (1).

So what is the truth here?

Comment: Tried it and the equalizer trick works. Can someone explain how this is possible? Are equalizers not performing convolution when cutting?

Comment: You are more likely to get a professional's viewpoint on this by asking at [dsp.se]

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373455/532409