# Ensure properties in the result of discrete deconvolution

Tags: analysis, convolution, deconvolution

I need to perform deconvolution to obtain information about a vector b.

Let c=a*b the convolution operation (the inverse of our operation), I need to calculate b=c/a.

The vectors are afflicted by noise and so the result of deconvolution will suffer it.

I know some properties of the function b (it's monotone and b(0)=1), is there a way to make an approximate deconvolution ensuring that the resulting function b would have these properties?

Comment: Yes there are many ways. In fact it is a whole field of research, so it is kind of hard to say any particular method.

Comment: Also you probably mean that you want to preserve some "properties", not proprieties?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the message, can you link me some papers about it?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373455/532409